# ¿Cómo hacer una petición POST y enviar un request a una ruta en laravel desde controlador?

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, post

Buen día

tengo un controlador que realiza una inserción de datos, y luego de insertarlos busco redireccionar a una ruta tipo POST enviándole un request que recibe el otro controlador, pero no encuentro como realizarla

Agradecería bastante quien pueda ayudarme.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Podrías redirigir directamente al action del otro controlador sin pasar por la ruta https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#redirecting-controller-actions

Comment: Por lo que veo no es posible hacer eso porque `redireccionar` significa moverse a otra `URL` y esto implica hacer una peticion `GET`, por lo que si quieres pasar datos tienes que usar ese metodo. O una solucion a parte serie enviar una nueva peticion `POST` desde ese controlador y no usar un `redireccionamiento`

Comment: Podrías explicar por qué quieres hacer eso? Es necesario que muestres el formulario o simplemente necesitas hacer el procesamiento del controlador?

Answer (score -1):

Creo que con hacer un redirect sería suficiente:

```
return redirect('/ruta_de_tu_controller');
```

Comment: No, sale este error

Comment: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: además necesito enviar un request por body

Comment: El error que te da ahora es porque en tu formulario realizas en envío de datos mediante el método GET mientras que en el fichero de mapeado de rutas (routes.php o web.php) está definida con el método POST